# How to build JavaScriptCore for iOS device?

Tags: javascript, ios, embedding

I've downloaded Webkit nightly build. I open JavaScriptCore and built it. Compilation done without any error. But the output was a Framework contains only OS X binary. I tried unchecking 'build active architecture only' but only desktop architectures built. (I looked in the binary with lipo tool)

Is there any simple way to do this? I'm expecting static library can be linked to my iOS app project. I'm trying to embed JSC as in-game script engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked [phoboslab's repo](https://github.com/phoboslab/JavaScriptCore-iOS) and updated it to the latest verson from WebKit (as of last friday). It is compatible with iOS 5 and 6 and includes the Objective-C to Javascript bridge to be featured in iOS 7 (no private frameworks or function used).

You can find the repo on GitHub at:
https://github.com/darionco/JavaScriptCore-iOS

I also added a ZIP file to the repo containing the library (.a) and needed header files for convenience.

Cheers!

Comment: Just for note: JavaScriptCore is a part of public framework of iOS7. And I think this still would be a good choice for compatibility.

Comment: Also of note: Apple won't accept apps binding to the new JavascriptCore framework which would be available on iOS 5/6, so this approach is required if you've got an iOS app which needs to be backwards-compatible. Thanks, @Dario!

Comment: Spoke too soon - this builds fine, but I'm getting the classic "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" error during build after following the guidance on the project GitHub page. Any ideas, folks?

Comment: Two things, there is a target that combines the different targets to make a multi-slice binary, the repo's readme has some build instructions on how to do that. The other possibility is that I didn't include the new 64-bit target (it wasn't available when I made this) so you would have to add it to the project.

Comment: Also Yavor Georgiev has taken the time to improve the fork greatly: https://github.com/fealebenpae/JavaScriptCore-iOS

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an XCode project for JavaScriptCore that is part of the WebKit codebase.  I was able to change the target SDK to iOS and the target architecture to arm6/arm7, and the dynamic framework built fine.  You'll need to compile it to a static library, of course, so you'll need to create a new static library target for iOS and copy everything under Targets->JavaScriptCore into your new static library target.  It may be a little tricky, but it might work.

Comment: I vote this up instead of choosing as right answer because I decided to use another scripting engine so it's hard to make time to test this at currently. I hope this way work, and thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: Ryan, is it possible to add more details about your build process? I would like to try that as well, but I have no idea what needs to be changed in the project settings.

Comment: What did you decide on @Eonil?

Comment: @David I switched to `Lua`. It is obvious better choice for that.

Comment: @Eonil, interesting, thanks for the info.  Do you have to bind to the native drawing calls from Lua yourself? Or do you use some existing library?

Comment: @David I didn't map native drawing calls to Lua. I didn't used script heavily. My game is processing-intensive, and iPhone is too weak. So I realized that betting on scripting is too risky. Currently, I'm using Lua script for some kind of environment/stage setup, debugging support only. If you're looking for good Lua based framework, you can bet on  http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/

Comment: Note, I'm not using *Corona*. It's just a recommendation.

Comment: what about armv7s and ios6 SDK ? it is not working... I cant compile.